# ReSharper configuration for indentation of anonymous methods?

Tags: c#, resharper, indentation

If I ask ReSharper to reformat the current code:

```
SomeMethodThatIsGivenAnAnonymousMethod(delegate
{
    Test();
});
```

Then it reformats it like this:

```
SomeMethodThatIsGivenAnAnonymousMethod(delegate
                                           {
                                               Test();
                                           });
```

I can at most coax it to line up the braces with the delegate keyword. Is there any way I can coax it into indenting it back to the original way?

Comment: Gonna bookmark this one as I gave up in my own attempts at getting it to work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try Formatting Style | Other | Indent Anonymous Method Body.  If I turn this off, I get the original format you describe.

Comment: You're a bl**y lifesaver! Excellent! You won't believe how many times I've been hunting for that one!

Comment: In addition to above, there was one more option I had to change: **Formatting Style | Braces Layout | Anonymous method declaration**. I set the value to **At next line (BSD style)**.